# Wordpress 404 PAGE

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I recently migrated my site to a new domain and a sub dir under that domain. quivinat.com/quv1anTemp/ My Wordpress 404 page is going to an old page seems to be from where my site use to be because it is pulling in the old header. I did a test and I modified the 404.php but it did not have any effect on the 404 landing page.

Not sure what is going on.

Any suggestions.

Try typing in "quivinat.com/quv1antemp/ and you will notice that the header is says HotFoot. This is my old header.

.htaccess file is as follows

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /quv1anTemp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /quv1anTemp/index.php
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the dashboard under General > Settings the Wordpress URL and Site Address must be changed to use the new domain.